# Python add dataframe col with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a question about python's dataframes.

I've a dataframe with data from xlsx like :

```
years = np.arange(2000, 2010)
engine = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Engine': np.repeat(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 10),
'Year': np.tile(np.arange(2000, 2010), 4),
'Energy': np.random.randint(10, 100, 40)
})
```

And I've a dict like :

```
Max = {'A' : 100, 'B' : 200, 'C' : 300, 'D' : 400}
```

And I'd like to add to my df a col named 'Max' and this col will match the dict key with the Engine name and add the dict value to the Max col.

Someone can help me ?

Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Please try use [pd.series.map()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
   df['Max']=df.Engine.map(Max)
```

[image]